# What is the secular version of the word Chaplain?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am a celebrant ceremony designer and trainer, and I am looking for a word to use for our research and performance of pet funerals.  Currently internationally people use the word Animal Chaplain, but for the non-religious the Chaplaincy word isn't quite right.  Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: Why not come up with something new? AniChap? (it's a start)

Comment: Interestingly, the idea of a secular chaplain is an oxymoron given the dictionary meaning is: "a member of the clergy attached to a private chapel, institution, ship, branch of the armed forces, etc." But the modern usage of chaplain appears to be closer to _counselor_ than _pastor_.

Comment: I'll just leave this here. http://www.militaryatheists.org/chaplain.html

Answer (score 4):

If it is limited to conducting the funerals, you could use Pet Eulogist. To eulogy/eulogize has no religious denotation, since the roots simply mean "good words" or "speak well of."

A more general administrator/conductor of a ceremony would be an **officiant**.

Answer (score 3):

How about celebrant? It seems you already use this term...Humanist 'ministers' (i.e. the people that carry out Humanist weddings, funerals etc) also call themselves celebrants.

Answer (score 2):

I'd be tempted to use a word like *facilitator*.

Comment: Then please resist it......

Comment: @Martin: +1 I'd say that *facilitating* a pet funeral might imply that one was also the euthanizer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Chaplain does sound like the right word (after all, it refers to a position of ministry, not of religious function). "Animal Chaplain" sounds like you minister to animals, which isn't quite right. "Animal Bereavement Chaplain" would seem accurate, if not pithy.

Comment: Actually, _chaplain_ specifically refers to a member of the clergy serving a particular area or group of people. (At least, this is what my dictionary says.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want something to do with a funeral without being religious:

> Animal Undertaker

Comment: An undertaker isn't a celebrant, though; they bring the body to the ceremony, but have no further official part.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a single word answer unless you make a new word, then you risk not being understood.  I'd suggest either *pet funeral director* if you only oversee the funeral or *pet mortician* if you also offer embalming.

Answer (score 0):

If the context is clear, you could use [*master of ceremonies*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/master+of+ceremonies):

> 1. a person who presides over a public ceremony, formal dinner, or entertainment, introducing the events, performers, etc.

On a less serious note, you could also try *speaker for the dead*.

Answer (score -1):

Personally, were I to be a member of Christendom I would find it quite offensive and pretentious to use such words. From the definition of chaplain I fail to see how it could possibly apply to your scenario.

I thank you for looking a proper way to avoid this offensive word and suggest the approach suggested by Citizen.

Maybe *anitaker*? (animal + undertaker). It could be quite catchy, even. Barring that, I like *pet eulogist.*